# Non-continuous variable supplied to scale_x_continuous in ggplot2 geom_point graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table that has two columns both of them are continuous data. I checked the csv file to make sure there are only numeric values in those columns. However, when I plot them one of them seems to be taken as non-continuous data, and I get: `Error: Non-continuous variable supplied to scale_x_continuous.`
This is a small version of my table

```
   budget    gross
1  234       4234
2  42342     2323
3  22165     346
4  290       452
...
```

I am trying to create a scatter plot where the gross numbers are in the y axis and the budget in the x axis. 
I tried this but I get the fore-mentioned error.

```
p <- ggplot(test, aes(Budget, Gross))+geom_point(alpha=I(1/5), aes(colour=Budget))+ opts(titles="Movies per Year", panel.grid.major = theme_blank(), panel.grid.minor = theme_blank())+scale_x_continuous()
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Your data has columns budget and gross, but your calls to ggplot use title case versions of those - but that's not what causes the error. +1 for the factor theory by Matt

Comment: There's something in that data.frame that makes `read.*` function think the column(s) is a factor. If you're using Excel or OOCalc, there may be values that have `'` in front of them (or some other contaminant - if you are able to post your file online I'd be more than happy to have a look at it). They may appear values, but they're not. I always advocate a clean data.frame, but that's just my pedantic side talking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `class(test$Budget)`.  Odds are that R believes that your column is a factor.  If that's so, you can get around the problem by using the `stringsAsFactors` option, either inside of your `read.csv()`:

```
test <- read.csv(file = "yourdata.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or set it for the entire session:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

From personal experience, I'd recommend the latter.  I start all of my scripts that way, actually - most functions that need factors will coerce other vector types as necessary, and if they don't, *then* I'll manually specify it.  But having a bunch of vectors lurking in your data will cause you nothing but headaches.